# The add product function isn't working for me in Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider, dart-null-safety

I am creating a simple Shop app where I implement logic of adding our own product to list and update the existing product in the list. The update is going totally fine but whenever I tried to add new product sometime the app crashes and some time the result is reflect anything.

Here is my code. All entities are of type String except price (int).

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    import 'package:shop_app/provider/product.dart';
    import 'package:shop_app/provider/product_provider.dart';
    
    class EditProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      static const routname = '/edit-product-screen';
      const EditProductScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<EditProductScreen> createState() => _EditProductScreenState();
    }
    
    class _EditProductScreenState extends State<EditProductScreen> {
      final _priceFocusNode = FocusNode();
      final _descriptionFocusNode = FocusNode();
      final _imageUrlController = TextEditingController();
      final _imageUrlFocusNode = FocusNode();
      final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      var _editedProduct = Product(
        id: '',
        title: '',
        price: 0,
        description: '',
        imageUrl: '',
      );
      var _initValues = {
        'title': '',
        'description': '',
        'price': '',
        'imageUrl': '',
      };
      var _isInit = true;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        _imageUrlFocusNode.addListener(_updateImageUrl);
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      void didChangeDependencies() {
        if (_isInit) {
          final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
          // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
          if (productId != null) {
            _editedProduct = Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false)
                .findById(productId.toString());
            _initValues = {
              'title': _editedProduct.title,
              'description': _editedProduct.description,
              'price': _editedProduct.price.toString(),
              // 'imageUrl': _editedProduct.imageUrl,
              'imageUrl': '',
            };
            _imageUrlController.text = _editedProduct.imageUrl;
          }
        }
        _isInit = false;
        super.didChangeDependencies();
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _imageUrlFocusNode.removeListener(_updateImageUrl);
        _priceFocusNode.dispose();
        _descriptionFocusNode.dispose();
        _imageUrlController.dispose();
        _imageUrlFocusNode.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      void _updateImageUrl() {
        if (!_imageUrlFocusNode.hasFocus) {
          if ((!_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('http') &&
                  !_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('https')) ||
              (!_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.png') &&
                  !_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.jpg') &&
                  !_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.jpeg'))) {
            return;
          }
          setState(() {});
        }
      }
    
      void _saveForm() {
        final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
        if (!isValid) {
          return;
        }
        _form.currentState!.save();
        // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
        if (_editedProduct.id != null) {
          Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false)
              .updateProduct(_editedProduct.id, _editedProduct);
        } else {
          Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: true)
              .addProduct(_editedProduct);
        }
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Edit Product'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
                onPressed: _saveForm,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Form(
              key: _form,
              child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    initialValue: _initValues['title'],
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_priceFocusNode);
                    },
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please provide a value.';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _editedProduct = Product(
                          title: value.toString(),
                          price: _editedProduct.price,
                          description: _editedProduct.description,
                          imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                          id: _editedProduct.id,
                          isFav: _editedProduct.isFav);
                    },
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    initialValue: _initValues['price'],
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Price'),
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    focusNode: _priceFocusNode,
                    onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_descriptionFocusNode);
                    },
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please enter a price.';
                      }
                      if (double.tryParse(value) == null) {
                        return 'Please enter a valid number.';
                      }
                      if (double.parse(value) <= 0) {
                        return 'Please enter a number greater than zero.';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _editedProduct = Product(
                          title: _editedProduct.title,
                          price: int.parse(value.toString()),
                          description: _editedProduct.description,
                          imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                          id: _editedProduct.id,
                          isFav: _editedProduct.isFav);
                    },
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    initialValue: _initValues['description'],
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description'),
                    maxLines: 3,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    focusNode: _descriptionFocusNode,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please enter a description.';
                      }
                      if (value.length < 10) {
                        return 'Should be at least 10 characters long.';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _editedProduct = Product(
                        title: _editedProduct.title,
                        price: _editedProduct.price,
                        description: value.toString(),
                        imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                        id: _editedProduct.id,
                        isFav: _editedProduct.isFav,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 8,
                          right: 10,
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            width: 1,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: _imageUrlController.text.isEmpty
                            ? const Text('Enter a URL')
                            : FittedBox(
                                child: Image.network(
                                  _imageUrlController.text,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextFormField(
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Image URL'),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                          controller: _imageUrlController,
                          focusNode: _imageUrlFocusNode,
                          onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                            _saveForm();
                          },
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value!.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Please enter an image URL.';
                            }
                            if (!value.startsWith('http') &&
                                !value.startsWith('https')) {
                              return 'Please enter a valid URL.';
                            }
                            if (!value.endsWith('.png') &&
                                !value.endsWith('.jpg') &&
                                !value.endsWith('.jpeg')) {
                              return 'Please enter a valid image URL.';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          onSaved: (value) {
                            _editedProduct = Product(
                              title: _editedProduct.title,
                              price: _editedProduct.price,
                              description: _editedProduct.description,
                              imageUrl: value.toString(),
                              id: _editedProduct.id,
                              isFav: _editedProduct.isFav,
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Here is my Product Class

```dart
class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final int price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFav;

  Product(
      {required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.description,
      required this.price,
      required this.imageUrl,
      this.isFav = false});

  void toggleFavStatus() {
    isFav = !isFav;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Here is My Product Provider Class

```dart
class ProductsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  // ignore: prefer_final_fields
  List<Product> _items = [
    Product(
      id: 'p1',
      title: 'Red Shirt',
      description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
      price: 29,
      imageUrl:
          'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p2',
      title: 'Trousers',
      description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
      price: 59,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p3',
      title: 'Yellow Scarf',
      description: 'Warm and cozy - exactly what you need for the winter.',
      price: 19,
      imageUrl:
          'https://live.staticflickr.com/4043/4438260868_cc79b3369d_z.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p4',
      title: 'A Pan',
      description: 'Prepare any meal you want.',
      price: 49,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg/1024px-Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg',
    ),
  ];

  List<Product> get items {
    // if (_showFavoritesOnly) {
    //   return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
    // }
    return [..._items];
  }

  List<Product> get favoriteItems {
    return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFav).toList();
  }

  Product findById(String id) {
    return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }

  void showFavoritesOnly() {
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void showAll() {
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addProduct(Product product) {
    final newProduct = Product(
      title: product.title,
      description: product.description,
      price: product.price,
      imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    );
    _items.add(newProduct);
    // _items.insert(0, newProduct); // at the start of the list
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateProduct(String id, Product newProduct) {
    final prodIndex = _items.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    if (prodIndex >= 0) {
      _items[prodIndex] = newProduct;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {}
  }

  void deleteProduct(String id) {
    _items.removeWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your product and product provider

Comment: I just added Have a look Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current add event trigger the update product method. based on your condition, it is

```dart
  var _editedProduct = Product(
    id: '',
```

But on saved you are checking null,

```dart
  if (_editedProduct.id != null) {
```

If you like to check null, you need to make id nullable like
`String? id` .

```dart
class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String? id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final int price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFav;

  Product(
      {this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.description,
      required this.price,
      required this.imageUrl,
      this.isFav = false});
```

And use  `listen: false`

```dart
 void _saveForm() {
    final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }
    _form.currentState!.save();
    // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
    if (_editedProduct.id != null) {
      Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .updateProduct(_editedProduct.id!, _editedProduct);
    } else {
      Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(
        context,
        listen: false,
      ).addProduct(_editedProduct);
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

Full test snippet

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => ProductsProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: App(),
    ),
  );
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          final route = MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              return EditProductScreen();
            },
          );

          Navigator.of(context).push(route);
        },
      ),
      body: Consumer<ProductsProvider>(
        builder: (context, value, child) => ListView.builder(
          itemCount: value.items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text("${value.items[index].id}"),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class EditProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routname = '/edit-product-screen';
  const EditProductScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EditProductScreen> createState() => _EditProductScreenState();
}

class _EditProductScreenState extends State<EditProductScreen> {
  final _priceFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _descriptionFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _imageUrlController = TextEditingController();
  final _imageUrlFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  Product _editedProduct = Product(
    title: '',
    price: 0,
    description: '',
    imageUrl: '',
  );
  var _initValues = {
    'title': '',
    'description': '',
    'price': '',
    'imageUrl': '',
  };
  var _isInit = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _imageUrlFocusNode.addListener(_updateImageUrl);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
      // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
      if (productId != null) {
        _editedProduct = Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .findById(productId.toString());
        _initValues = {
          'title': _editedProduct.title,
          'description': _editedProduct.description,
          'price': _editedProduct.price.toString(),
          // 'imageUrl': _editedProduct.imageUrl,
          'imageUrl': '',
        };
        _imageUrlController.text = _editedProduct.imageUrl;
      }
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _imageUrlFocusNode.removeListener(_updateImageUrl);
    _priceFocusNode.dispose();
    _descriptionFocusNode.dispose();
    _imageUrlController.dispose();
    _imageUrlFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _updateImageUrl() {
    if (!_imageUrlFocusNode.hasFocus) {
      if ((!_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('http') &&
              !_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('https')) ||
          (!_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.png') &&
              !_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.jpg') &&
              !_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.jpeg'))) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void _saveForm() {
    final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }
    _form.currentState!.save();
    // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
    if (_editedProduct.id != null) {
      Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .updateProduct(_editedProduct.id!, _editedProduct);
    } else {
      Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(
        context,
        listen: false,
      ).addProduct(_editedProduct);
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Edit Product'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
            onPressed: _saveForm,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _form,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['title'],
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_priceFocusNode);
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please provide a value.';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedProduct = Product(
                      title: value.toString(),
                      price: _editedProduct.price,
                      description: _editedProduct.description,
                      imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                      isFav: _editedProduct.isFav);
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['price'],
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Price'),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                focusNode: _priceFocusNode,
                onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_descriptionFocusNode);
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter a price.';
                  }
                  if (double.tryParse(value) == null) {
                    return 'Please enter a valid number.';
                  }
                  if (double.parse(value) <= 0) {
                    return 'Please enter a number greater than zero.';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedProduct = Product(
                      title: _editedProduct.title,
                      price: int.tryParse(value.toString()) ?? 0,
                      description: _editedProduct.description,
                      imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                      isFav: _editedProduct.isFav);
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['description'],
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description'),
                maxLines: 3,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                focusNode: _descriptionFocusNode,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter a description.';
                  }
                  if (value.length < 10) {
                    return 'Should be at least 10 characters long.';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedProduct = Product(
                    title: _editedProduct.title,
                    price: _editedProduct.price,
                    description: value.toString(),
                    imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                    isFav: _editedProduct.isFav,
                  );
                },
              ),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 8,
                      right: 10,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 1,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: _imageUrlController.text.isEmpty
                        ? const Text('Enter a URL')
                        : FittedBox(
                            child: Image.network(
                              _imageUrlController.text,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Image URL'),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      controller: _imageUrlController,
                      focusNode: _imageUrlFocusNode,
                      onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                        _saveForm();
                      },
                      validator: (value) {
                        ///* enable theses
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter an image URL.';
                        }
                        if (!value.startsWith('http') &&
                            !value.startsWith('https')) {
                          return 'Please enter a valid URL.';
                        }
                        if (!value.endsWith('.png') &&
                            !value.endsWith('.jpg') &&
                            !value.endsWith('.jpeg')) {
                          return 'Please enter a valid image URL.';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _editedProduct = Product(
                          title: _editedProduct.title,
                          price: _editedProduct.price,
                          description: _editedProduct.description,
                          imageUrl: value.toString(),
                          id: _editedProduct.id,
                          isFav: _editedProduct.isFav,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String? id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final int price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFav;

  Product(
      {this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.description,
      required this.price,
      required this.imageUrl,
      this.isFav = false});

  void toggleFavStatus() {
    isFav = !isFav;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class ProductsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  // ignore: prefer_final_fields
  List<Product> _items = [
    Product(
      id: 'p1',
      title: 'Red Shirt',
      description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
      price: 29,
      imageUrl:
          'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p2',
      title: 'Trousers',
      description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
      price: 59,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p3',
      title: 'Yellow Scarf',
      description: 'Warm and cozy - exactly what you need for the winter.',
      price: 19,
      imageUrl:
          'https://live.staticflickr.com/4043/4438260868_cc79b3369d_z.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p4',
      title: 'A Pan',
      description: 'Prepare any meal you want.',
      price: 49,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg/1024px-Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg',
    ),
  ];

  List<Product> get items {
    // if (_showFavoritesOnly) {
    //   return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
    // }
    return [..._items];
  }

  List<Product> get favoriteItems {
    return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFav).toList();
  }

  Product findById(String id) {
    return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }

  void showFavoritesOnly() {
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void showAll() {
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addProduct(Product product) {
     
    final newProduct = Product(
      title: product.title,
      description: product.description,
      price: product.price,
      imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    );
    _items.add(newProduct);
    // _items.insert(0, newProduct); // at the start of the list
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateProduct(String id, Product newProduct) {
   
    final prodIndex = _items.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    if (prodIndex >= 0) {
      _items[prodIndex] = newProduct;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {}
  }

  void deleteProduct(String id) {
    _items.removeWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just open a VPN app on your pc, also open VPN on your phone where you are running the code.
Cause firebase is not available for all countries.